# 2D игра "под углом" Unity

Tags: unity3d, tilemap

Хотелось бы узнать как достичь такого результата:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть камера находится вверху, а стены имеют объем. Так же интересно, как спрятать персонажа, если он зашел за стену. Каким способом можно добиться такого эффекта через Tilemap.

Comment: они не объемные,просто(скорее всего) камера повернута на 70 градусов

Comment: Это классика изометрии, ресурсов на тему таких игр в интернете навалом.

Answer (score 4):

> То есть камера находится вверху, а стены имеют объем.

Обьемность стен -- просто работа художника. И не более того. На практике будет просто текстура пола локации. + 2 части текстуры коллон отдельно.

Колоны размещаются в нужных местах, но коллайдеры размещены у колон не на полный размер картинки а на ее часть:

Например так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это даст возможность

1. стоять перед колонной (ведь нижняя часть колонны лежит на слою ниже персонажа и коллайдер отвечающий за низ персонажа не пересекается с колонной)
2. проходить за колонной (ведь верхняя часть находится выше персонажа и не имеет коллайдера)

Вся колонна (и верхний слой и нижний с коллайдером) является префабом и просто размещается на уровне в нужных местах.

Comment: красная стена ниже персонажа, темная стена выше

Comment: Справедливости ради, вместо слоев для отрисовки можно использовать координаты, чем кто "выше", то рисуется позже всех.

Comment: А хотя нет, слишком комплексная игра, через координаты не получится.